# The Jenkins build for executing a sh file is successful, but when checked in backend (terminal) , the sh file hasn't started yet

Tags: jenkins, build, sh, jobs, ssh-tunnel

In my Jenkins job when I try to run the following line, I'm getting response as the build is successful however, the .sh file is not getting executed in the back end (terminal) :

ssh -T username@ip ‘sh /path/file.sh’

#the command is supposed to start a service

The same .sh file runs in backend (terminal) when executed manually from backend.

The same command is working for other servers.

Comment: try running the ssh command with the `-vvv` flag to get more verbose output and see if there are any issues with the connection.

Comment: @DanTe i tried -vvv but there were no issues in that too

Comment: It seems more likely that the command runs, but something subsequently causes the service to shut down. Without more details, we can really only speculate.